# How to solve this specific Probability given 2 independent events

Tags: probability, independence

> In a zoo, there are 1 billion monkeys. Probability that a monkey has seen a banyan 
>       tree is 0.6.
>
> Prob that monkey has seen a mango tree is 0.65.
>
> What is the minimum percentage of monkeys in the zoo who have seen both the trees?
>
> OPTIONS Given- 25%,39%,40%,60%

```
MY Approach 1:

prob of seeing banyan tree, P(A)=0.6
prob of seeing mango tree, P(B)=0.65
prob OF seeing min both the tree, P(A intersaction 
using this formula,
p(A union B)= p(A)+p(b)-p(A intersaction B)-------(1)
here we use max prob is 1 , so p(A Union B) =1
putting all values in eqn (1) we get 
p(A intersaction B )= 0.25.... i.e. 25%
SO OPTION (B) IS CORRECT

 IS it Right Approach?
```

My Approach2

```
P(B)=0.6
P(M)=0.65
P(B intersection U)=0.6*0.65=0.39 //for 2 independent events
Ans is 39% 

Both have different answers
IS it Right Approach?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will assume that by writing "Probability that a monkey has seen a banyan tree is 0.6.", you mean that 60% of the monkeys actually saw an banyan tree. (Otherwise the answer is 0, since it is possible that no monkey ever saw a single tree)

Now, using the formula $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$, we know that, since $P(A\cup B) \leq 1$, $P(A \cap B) \geq 0.25$.
Last but not least, to be sure the answer is 25% we must find a situation where 25% of the monkeys have seen both trees. So let's consider the following: 25%of the monkeys saw both trees, 40% saw only the mango trees and 35% saw only the banyan trees. This situation fits the conditions, hence the answer in B.

Comment: Regarding your approach, it will mostly give you the right results, but it isn't rigorous enough: for instance, when you decide that $P(A \cup B)=1$, you should explain why it is the "worst" case and why it can happen.

Comment: Can you given an example Sir for any worst case .and also how u calculated 40% saw only mango trees?

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to create a situation where 25% of the monkeys saw both trees, 60% saw banyan trees and 65% saw mango trees. So, should such a situation exist, how many monkeys saw only mango trees? I know 65% saw a mango tree, and 25% saw both mango and banyan trees. Hence, 65%-25%=40% of the monkeys saw only a mango tree. i do similarly for the banyan trees, and now I have values for every possible combination of trees. I finally verify that those values are legal (they are positive and their sum is 1), and I have my example, which proves 25% is the right answer.

Comment: GBQT Okay Great Sir.But one more thing i was confused when i also used this approach(See Edit).Why can't this be used?

Comment: Well, I think that in this exercise the events aren't supposed to be independent. If they were, you know for sure that $P(A \cap B)$ IS $0.6*0.65=0.39$, so there would be no point about talking about a minimal value, since it is fixed. However, if the events are supposed independents the 1st approach would be wrong(since in my example, the events aren't independent) and the 2nd would be correct.

Comment: @GBTQ Yes u explained clearly.We should not consider it independent events because there would be no point talking about minimal value.

Comment: Well, it depends of the exercise: does it clearly states the events are independent? If yes, they are, if no they may or may not be independent. I just thought it was surprising to have independent events in such an exercise

Comment: It is not written.

Comment: Then the answer is B.